# Issues with GStreamer pipeline in OpenCV for H.264 Encoded Camera Stream

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am relatively new to GStreamer pipelines, and I'm currently working on a camera service where I need to read an H.264 encoded camera stream using OpenCV and GStreamer.

The following GStreamer pipeline works fine:

```
const char *pipeline_str = "v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, framerate=30/1 ! x264enc ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! appsink";
cv::VideoCapture cap(pipeline_str, cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);

if (!cap.isOpened()) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to open appsink as VideoCapture\n";
    return;
}
```

However, when I try a similar pipeline without the H.264 decoding part:

```
const char *pipeline_str = "v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, framerate=30/1 ! x264enc ! h264parse ! appsink";
cv::VideoCapture cap(pipeline_str, cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);

if (!cap.isOpened()) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to open appsink as VideoCapture\n";
    return;
}
```

It fails to open the appsink as VideoCapture. I'm not sure what the problem is with the encoded stream in the non-working scenario.

Could someone please help me understand why the pipeline without H.264 decoding is not working as expected? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me differentiate between raw video and compressed video (eg. h264). The description is simplified but should be enough to point out where the problem is.
In raw video, each video frame is stored without compression so as a series of bytes for each pixel (3 bytes per pixel for RGB or BGR frames or 2 bytes for YUV).
For compressed video a video frame is compressed to lower memory and you need an encoder to convert it back to raw video.

Lets examine your pipeline:
`v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, framerate=30/1` -->**raw video here**

`x264enc` --> **h264 encoded video**

`h264parse ! avdec_h264` --> **raw video again**

`videoconvert ! appsink` --> **still raw video**

In the first pipeline you are passing raw video to appsink, while in the second - compressed h264 video data.
`VideoCapture` requires raw video, that's why it cannot open compressed video frames.

I believe you're trying to send h264 compressed data and read it in OpenCV for further processing. If so, you need to decode it first using `avdec_h264`.

Comment: Thanks for reply , Actually I want to implement a GStreamer pipeline to continuously record a 7-second buffer of H.264 encoded video from past. Upon request, I aim to copy the buffered data for processing, including writing the copied content to a file and converting it to an OpenCV Mat, all while maintaining the uninterrupted flow of continuous recording.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @piotr, the main cause is that opencv cannot yet process H264 buffers, at least from gstreamer backend. Just see [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/0052d46b8e33c7bfe0e1450e4bff28b88f455570/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp#L991C39-L992C57) for supported formats.

Another point with H264 is that for being decoded it may require a previous key frame, so all buffers before a key frame may not be usable. This might  make the 7s delay of your case more uncertain if you don't have access to camera's H264 encoding properties.

Although there may be solutions with gstreamer programming, the simplest way I can see for your case would be using opencv such as:

```cpp
#include <signal.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

/* Some static variables that would be used from sig handler */
static int width = 0;
static int height = 0;
static float fps = 0.f;
static int cur_frame_nb = -1;
static int last_record_frame_nb = -1;
static int cur_video_nb = -1;
static cv::VideoWriter* writer = NULL;


/* Create a video writer with gstreamer encoding from opencv BGR format with H264 into MP4 container file */
cv::VideoWriter * createVideoWriter() {
    char writer_pipeline_str[128] = {0};
    sprintf(writer_pipeline_str, "appsrc ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse ! qtmux ! filesink location=video_%02d.mp4", cur_video_nb);
    cv::VideoWriter* writer = new cv::VideoWriter(writer_pipeline_str, cv::CAP_GSTREAMER, 0, fps, cv::Size(width, height));
    return writer;
}


/* Signal handler that would asynchronously start a video capture for 7s */
void my_sighandler(int s){
    if (writer) {
       std::cerr << "Video recording already in process, ignoring" << std::endl;
       return;
    }
    
    printf("Start recording video %02d\n", ++cur_video_nb);
    writer = createVideoWriter();
    last_record_frame_nb = cur_frame_nb + (int)(7*fps);
}


int
main ()
{
    /* You would need an opencv build with gstreamer backend support. You can check uncommenting the following line */
    // std::cout << cv::getBuildInformation() << std::endl; 

    /* Install handler for catching Ctrl-C that would create a videoWriter encoding H264 and putting into a MP4 file for 7s */
    struct sigaction sigIntHandler;
    sigIntHandler.sa_handler = my_sighandler;
    sigemptyset(&sigIntHandler.sa_mask);
    sigIntHandler.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sigIntHandler, NULL);

    /* Create a capture from H264 simulated camera */
    const char* cap_str = "videotestsrc pattern=ball is-live=1 do-timestamp=1 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=320,height=240,framerate=30/1 ! x264enc ! queue name=cam\
        cam. ! video/x-h264,width=320,height=240,framerate=30/1 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! queue ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink drop=1";
    cv::VideoCapture cap(cap_str, cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);
    if (!cap.isOpened ()) {
      std::cout << "Failed to open camera." << std::endl;
      return (-1);
    
    }
    std::cout << "Video Capture opened (backend: " << cap.getBackendName() << ")" << std::endl;
    width = (int) cap.get (cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    height = (int) cap.get (cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    fps = cap.get (cv::CAP_PROP_FPS);
    std::cout << "Framing: " << width << " x " << height << " @" << fps << " FPS" <<std::endl;
 
    unsigned int bufferDepth = (unsigned int)(7 * fps);
    boost::circular_buffer<cv::Mat> cb(bufferDepth);
 
    /* Loop until error or if you type 'q' with focus on the opencv GUI display window */
    cv::Mat frame_in, frame_out;
    while (1) {
       /* Read frame from capture */
       if (!cap.read (frame_in)) {
          std::cout << "Capture read error" << std::endl;
          break;
       }
       ++cur_frame_nb;
       cv::imshow("IPCam monitor",frame_in);
       cb.push_back(frame_in.clone());
       if(cb.size() == bufferDepth) {
           frame_out = cb.front();
           cb.pop_front();
           /* Manage writer if currently active */
           if (writer) {
               if (cur_frame_nb <= last_record_frame_nb)
                   writer->write(frame_out);
               else {
                   std::cout << "Stopping recording video " << cur_video_nb << std::endl;
                   writer->release();
                   delete writer;
                   writer = NULL;
               }
           }
           cv::imshow("Delayed output",frame_out);
       }
       if ('q' == cv::waitKey(1))
           break;
   }
   if(writer)
       writer->release();
   cap.release ();

   return 0;
}
```

Typing 'q' with focus on display window would exit.
Typing 'Ctrl-C' with focus on terminal where the app has been launched would start a 7s video recording.

Note that it is a simple starting point, this example would not support non integer fps nor more frames duration than a simple integer can hold, and maybe more other untested cases.